# An old, obsolete meaning for "hump"?

Tags: meaning

I stumbled upon one of Wallace Stevens' letters, dated to 1909, where he describes a Sunday walk. I'm intentionally quoting quite a bit of this text, to give the full context ([You can read it here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=0e_AdnL3IYkC&pg=PA158&dq=%22hump%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD3PaN7M7aAhUDYlAKHSX1Aac4HhDoAQg-MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22hump%22&f=false); bold added):

> "I am quite shattered by the walk I took yesterday - not less than
> thirty miles. [...] Yet it was, as you say, such a glorious day [...]
> I passed a camp [... where] they were broiling ham. [...] I did
> respond to that sugarey fragnance [...] You know - when you camp in
> wild places - and come in at the end of the day, you always find
> venison over the fire, or a dozen trouts - and then, there is the hot
> bread, and your pipe afterwards [...] and you fall asleep, so tired,
> so contented. [...] And when I reached home I was too dusty and worn
> out to write [...] I fell all over the bed **in a hump**. Next Sunday I
> hope to do the same thing.

It could be that I'm reading too much into it, but I couldn't find a satisfying definition for this usage of the word "hump" (Or the phrase "In a hump"). I'll paste here [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hump) as an example:

> **Definition of hump**
>
> **1** : a rounded protuberance: such as
>
> **a** : humpback 1
>
> **b** : a fleshy protuberance on the back of an animal (such as a camel,
> bison, or whale)
>
> **c** (1) : mound, hummock (2) : mountain, range the
> Himalayan hump
>
> **2** *British* : a fit of depression or sulking
>
> **3** : a
> difficult, trying, or critical phase or obstacle —often used in the
> phrase over the hump

What does it mean, in this context?

Comment: What is the dictionary definition??

Comment: @HotLicks, added

Comment: Sounds like "hump" has been used in a variant of "fell on the bed ***in a heap**"* as in all worn out and exhausted/ contented/ anxious (depending on the context) -- note too that poets and writers tend to make creative use of common and uncommon words @O.d

Comment: Think of the shape of a hump.  Think of the shape of a small humpbacked bridge.

Comment: (CONTINUED). Now imagine the shape on the bed when someone has collapsed onto it in a disordered heap.  That is what is meant.

Comment: Definition 1:c(1)

Comment: Yes, he was most definitely hitting the hay in a strange position. A person's body in relation to the flat surface of a bed could be described as a hump. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does in a hump mean, in this context?

From a 2008 article authored by a cancer patient:

> "and when I found out the cancer had returned and that I needed chemo,
>   I just fell **in a hump** on the floor"  [Santa Fe New Mexican](http://www.santafenewmexican.com/news/local_news/chris-calloway---jazz-diva-gracious-in-battle-with/article_05eb13a0-afcc-5273-bdfe-057453c2e52b.html)

Ngram shows plentiful use of **in a heap**, zero use of **in a hump** as used in this question.  I suspect *hump* here is a variant of *heap* as in your citation and mine.  The cancer stricken patient may have been in *the hump*  [BrE: a fit of depression; an emotional slump.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hump) as she fell *in a hump*.

As in:

> I fell in a hump, tired, exhausted and depressed.

And from *hump* etymology:  [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hump#Etymology)

> Probably borrowed from Middle Low German hump (“**heap**, hill, stump”),
>   or from Old Saxon *hump (“hill, **heap**, thick piece”)